# Finding values that satisfy a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $y(x) = A\cos(3x) + B\sin(3x)$ that satisfies a differential equation:
>
> $y'+y = 3\sin(3x)$,  how do I find values $A$ and $B$.

I have tried to derivate $y(x)$ and put the derivative and the original function to form:

$y = A\cos(3x) + B\sin(3x)$

$y' = 3B\cos(3x)-3A\sin(3x)$

$3B\cos(3x)-3A\sin(3x)+A\cos(3x)+B\sin(3x) = 3\sin(3x)$

I can not deduce the values or solve them.

Comment: Clue: Sine and cosine are linearly independent.  I suppose I could explain, but this is probably a homework of some kind...

Comment: Please check the usage of A and B, the problem statement is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

$$3B\cos(3x)-3A\sin(3x)+A\cos(3x)+B\sin(3x) = 3\sin(3x)$$
$$(3B+A)\cos(3x)+(B-3A)\sin(3x)= 3\sin(3x)+ \color {red}{0 \times \cos (3x)}$$
Now solve for $A,B$ the system of equations:
$$
\begin {cases}
3B+A=0 \\
B-3A=3
\end{cases}
$$